# Show all the fields when customizing a layout in SugarCRM 7

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I have created a Person module in SugarCRM7, with no additional fields.

[image: Record View]

I cannot see all the module's field, even if they exist. For instance I don't see any First name field, but when I try to create one I get an error saying that the field already exists.

[image: Showing error message]

Those fields are shown in the field list.
What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default fields `first_name` and `last_name` are special to Person-type modules. They are automatically concatenated by the system into a third field called `name` that you've likely noticed on other modules (everything has a `name`).

I believe that in Sugar7, the `name` field (or in a Person-style module's case, the `first_name` and `last_name`) is actually displayed above the topmost panel, so above the "Business Card" section.

There may be a way of overriding this, but you may end up modifying views pretty heavily. If I were you, and very determined to open up both name fields, I'd start with the view metadata and/or vardefs and see if there's a flag on the `first_name` field that says "studio" or "display" or "default" -- in the past flags like those have told the system whether or not they should be available or just show by default. Sugar7 views are different thing though, so I don't know if that's the trick or not.